# Javascript regular expression password validation having special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

I am trying to validate the password using regular expression. The password is getting updated if we have all the characters as alphabets. Where am i going wrong ? is the regular expression right ?

```
function validatePassword() {
    var newPassword = document.getElementById('changePasswordForm').newPassword.value;
    var minNumberofChars = 6;
    var maxNumberofChars = 16;
    var regularExpression  = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/;
    alert(newPassword); 
    if(newPassword.length < minNumberofChars || newPassword.length > maxNumberofChars){
        return false;
    }
    if(!regularExpression.test(newPassword)) {
        alert("password should contain atleast one number and one special character");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it's not getting evaluated?

Comment: if the new password should contain atleast one number and one special character. Even without these conditions the passsword is getting updated. I guess i have some problem with my regular expression.

Comment: Why are you setting such an arbitrary max length?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Use positive [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertions:

```
var regularExpression = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/;
```

Without it, your current regex only matches that you have 6 to 16 valid characters, it *doesn't* validate that it has *at least* a number, and *at least* a special character. That's what the lookahead above is for.

- `(?=.*[0-9])` - Assert a string has at least one number;
- `(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])` - Assert a string has at least one special character.

Comment: Possible to shorten regex to `/^(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[\w!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/`

Comment: /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/.test("12345678@12") will return true. What If I want to make it mandatory to include alphabets also?

Comment: Does anyone know why this regex expression would not work if I `var regexPttn = new RegExp("/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}$/");` For some reason using the creator breaks it.

Comment: @Bhuvan I used this answer to improve the expression provided. First of all including more special characters [space, hyphen, question mark, slash, backslash] and - above all - I increased the minimum number of characters because 6 characters passwords are highly insecure, especially if not flanked by login failures monitoring and/or 2FA. That said, I came to this: `^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[- ?!@#$%^&*\/\\])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])[a-zA-Z0-9- ?!@#$%^&*\/\\]{8,30}$`

Comment: I would change `[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,16}` to `.{6,16}` so that you can enter _any_ character (as long as the password contains the number and special character). I don't see any reason to reject a password simply because it contains a `+` for instance.

Comment: @VirtualProdigy you should use it like this var regularExpression = new RegExp('^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{8,20}$'); notice that we had to remove the slashes in the start and the end.

Comment: An uppercase character should be required it's not working for uppercase charector

Answer (score 58):

I use the following script for min 8 letter password, with at least a symbol, upper and lower case letters and a number

```
function checkPassword(str)
{
    var re = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/;
    return re.test(str);
}
```

Comment: Nice and precise. This way,  it satisfies the default password policy of AWS Cognito User Pools.

Comment: works well! Thank you

Comment: It does not accept gg@@ghgHHGG33h as a valid password though.

Comment: Why you don't have `_` underscore as it is also special character.

Answer (score 47):

```
function validatePassword() {
    var p = document.getElementById('newPassword').value,
        errors = [];
    if (p.length < 8) {
        errors.push("Your password must be at least 8 characters"); 
    }
    if (p.search(/[a-z]/i) < 0) {
        errors.push("Your password must contain at least one letter.");
    }
    if (p.search(/[0-9]/) < 0) {
        errors.push("Your password must contain at least one digit."); 
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        alert(errors.join("\n"));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

There is a certain issue in below answer as it is not checking whole string due to absence of [ ] while checking the characters and numerals, this is correct version

Comment: Add these if you want to restrict uppercase or lowercase:
`if (p.search(/[a-z]/) < 0) {
                        errors.push("Your password must contain at least one lowercase letter.")
                    }
                    if (p.search(/[A-Z]/) < 0) {
                        errors.push("Your password must contain at least one uppercase letter.")
                    }`

Comment: Here is a more dynamic solution, but basically uses this same concept: https://jsfiddle.net/omnius/p6uxjntg/

Answer (score 29):

you can make your own regular expression for javascript validation

```
    /^            : Start
    (?=.{8,})        : Length
    (?=.*[a-zA-Z])   : Letters
    (?=.*\d)         : Digits
    (?=.*[!#$%&? "]) : Special characters
    $/              : End



        (/^
        (?=.*\d)                //should contain at least one digit
        (?=.*[a-z])             //should contain at least one lower case
        (?=.*[A-Z])             //should contain at least one upper case
        [a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}         //should contain at least 8 from the mentioned characters

        $/)

Example:-   /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]{7,}$/
```

Comment: This failed for XYZ@123

Comment: @SarasArya add `@` in special characters. it will start working. It not rocket science!

Comment: @SarasArya, the requirement included at least 1 lowercase character. XYZ@123 has no lowercase characters.

Answer (score 21):

Don't try and do too much in one step. Keep each rule separate.

```
function validatePassword() {
    var p = document.getElementById('newPassword').value,
        errors = [];
    if (p.length < 8) {
        errors.push("Your password must be at least 8 characters");
    }
    if (p.search(/[a-z]/i) < 0) {
        errors.push("Your password must contain at least one letter."); 
    }
    if (p.search(/[0-9]/) < 0) {
        errors.push("Your password must contain at least one digit.");
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        alert(errors.join("\n"));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

**Regex for password**:

`/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z!#$%&? "])[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&?]{8,20}$/`

Took me a while to figure out the restrictions, but I did it!

Restrictions: (Note: I have used **>>** and **<<** to show the important characters)

1. Minimum 8 characters  `{>>8,20}`
2. Maximum 20 characters  `{8,>>20}`
3. At least one uppercase character  `(?=.*[A-Z])`
4. At least one lowercase character  `(?=.*[a-z])`
5. At least one digit  `(?=.*\d)`
6. At least one special character  `(?=.*[a-zA-Z >>!#$%&? "<<])[a-zA-Z0-9 >>!#$%&?<< ]`

Comment: What about the '@' and '^' symbols?

Comment: @prahack 

`/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[a-zA-Z!#$@^%&? "])[a-zA-Z0-9!#$@^%&?]{8,20}$/`

Comment: Special character requirement not working

Answer (score 13):

Here I'm extending @João Silva's answer. I had a requirement to check different parameters and throw different messages accordingly.

I divided the regex into different parts and now the `checkPasswordValidity(String)` function checks each regex part conditionally and throw different messages.

Hope the below example will help you to understand better!

```js
/**
 * @param {string} value: passwordValue
 */
const checkPasswordValidity = (value) => {
  const isNonWhiteSpace = /^\S*$/;
  if (!isNonWhiteSpace.test(value)) {
    return "Password must not contain Whitespaces.";
  }

  const isContainsUppercase = /^(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/;
  if (!isContainsUppercase.test(value)) {
    return "Password must have at least one Uppercase Character.";
  }

  const isContainsLowercase = /^(?=.*[a-z]).*$/;
  if (!isContainsLowercase.test(value)) {
    return "Password must have at least one Lowercase Character.";
  }

  const isContainsNumber = /^(?=.*[0-9]).*$/;
  if (!isContainsNumber.test(value)) {
    return "Password must contain at least one Digit.";
  }

  const isContainsSymbol =
    /^(?=.*[~`!@#$%^&*()--+={}\[\]|\\:;"'<>,.?/_₹]).*$/;
  if (!isContainsSymbol.test(value)) {
    return "Password must contain at least one Special Symbol.";
  }

  const isValidLength = /^.{10,16}$/;
  if (!isValidLength.test(value)) {
    return "Password must be 10-16 Characters Long.";
  }

  return null;
}

//------------------
// Usage/Example:
let yourPassword = "yourPassword123";
const message = checkPasswordValidity(yourPassword);

if (!message) {
  console.log("Hurray! Your Password is Valid and Strong.");
} else {
  console.log(message);
}
```

Also, we can combine all these regex patterns into single regex:

```
let regularExpression = /^(\S)(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[~`!@#$%^&*()--+={}\[\]|\\:;"'<>,.?/_₹])[a-zA-Z0-9~`!@#$%^&*()--+={}\[\]|\\:;"'<>,.?/_₹]{10,16}$/;
```

**Note:** The regex discussed above will check following patterns in the given input value/password:

- It must not contain any whitespace.
- It must contain at least one uppercase, one lowercase and one numeric character.
- It must contain at least one special character. [~`!@#$%^&*()--+={}[]|\:;"'<>,.?/_₹]
- Length must be between 10 to 16 characters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

### International UTF-8

None of the solutions here allows international characters, i.e. éÉáÁöÖæÆþÞóÓúÚ, but are only focused on the english alphabet.

The following regEx uses unicode, UTF-8, to recognise upper and lower case and thus, allow international characters:

```
// Match uppercase, lowercase, digit or #$!%*?& and make sure the length is 8 to 96 in length  
const pwdFilter = /^(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*[\d|@#$!%*?&])[\p{L}\d@#$!%*?&]{8,96}$/gmu

if (!pwdFilter.test(pwd)) {
    // Show error that password has to be adjusted to match criteria
}
```

This regEx

`/^(?=.*\p{Ll})(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*[\d|@#$!%*?&])[\p{L}\d@#$!%*?&]{8,96}$/gmu`

checks if an uppercase, lowercase, digit or #$!%*?& are used in the password. It also limits the length to be 8 minimum and maximum 96, the length of ‍ emojis count as more than one character in the length.
The `u` in the end, tells it to use UTF-8.

Comment: This works for some unicode, but not for e.g. Cyrillic or Chinese characters (possibly Arabic as well). All of these are likely to be expected in an international setting. Could you improve the RegEx to include these as well

Comment: @user9128309 you need to be more specific of what characters (glyphs) are not working, otherwise you are requesting a lot of work from me to investigate languages that I don't have much knowledge on.

Comment: Good point: you can use the following as test cases. Most international users will be making passwords in their native language. Also note that you may have combination of eg. Chinese and Latin alphabets in a password.

const pass3 = "Тест123...+*"; // cyrillic
const pass4 = "关键字157aA$89!"; //mandarin
const pass5 = "كلمة_سرية@123"; //arabic
const pass6 = "¿1-CómosediceAlbertoespañol?"; // spanish

Answer (score 4):

```
<div>
    <input type="password" id="password" onkeyup="CheckPassword(this)" />
</div>   

<div  id="passwordValidation" style="color:red" >
    
</div>

 function CheckPassword(inputtxt) 
    { 
    var passw= /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{7,15}$/;
    if(inputtxt.value.match(passw)) 
    { 
    $("#passwordValidation").html("")
    return true;
    }
    else
    { 
    $("#passwordValidation").html("min 8 characters which contain at least one numeric digit and a special character");
    return false;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of research, I was able to come up with this. This has more special characters

```
validatePassword(password) {
        const re = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*()+=-\?;,./{}|\":<>\[\]\\\' ~_]).{8,}/
        return re.test(password);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

it,s work perfect for me and i am sure will work for you guys checkout it easy and accurate

```
var regix = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=. 
            {8,})");

if(regix.test(password) == false ) {
     $('.messageBox').html(`<div class="messageStackError">
       password must be a minimum of 8 characters including number, Upper, Lower And 
       one special character
     </div>`);
}
else
{
        $('form').submit();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the password validation example I hope you like it.

Password validation with Uppercase, Lowercase, special character,number and limit 8 must be required.

```js
function validatePassword(){
    
   var InputValue = $("#password").val();
  var regex = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\$%\^&\*])(?=.{8,})");
    $("#passwordText").text(`Password value:- ${InputValue}`);
    
    if(!regex.test(InputValue)) {
         $("#error").text("Invalid Password");
    }
    else{
          $("#error").text("");
    }
}
```

```css
#password_Validation{
background-color:aliceblue;
padding:50px;
border:1px solid;
border-radius:5px;
}
#passwordText{
  color:green;
}
#error{
color:red;
}
#password{
margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="password_Validation">
  <h4>Password validation with Uppercase Lowercase special character and number must be required.</h4>
  <div>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <button type="button" onClick="validatePassword()">Submit</button>
   <div>
     <br/>
  <span id="passwordText"></span>
  <br/>
    <br/>
  <span id="error"></span>
<div>
```

Comment: It accepts spaces.

Comment: @MechaCode you can use this regex I hope you will get your goal. `^((?!.*[\s])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,15})`

Answer (score 2):

Very helpful. It will help end user to identify which char is missing/required while entering password.

Here is some improvement, ( here u could add your required special chars.)

```
function validatePassword(p) {
    //var p = document.getElementById('newPassword').value,
    const errors = [];
    if (p.length < 8) {
        errors.push("Your password must be at least 8 characters");
    }
    if (p.length > 32) {
        errors.push("Your password must be at max 32 characters");
    }
    if (p.search(/[a-z]/) < 0) {
        errors.push("Your password must contain at least one lower case letter."); 
    }
    if (p.search(/[A-Z]/) < 0) {
        errors.push("Your password must contain at least one upper case letter."); 
    }

    if (p.search(/[0-9]/) < 0) {
        errors.push("Your password must contain at least one digit.");
    }
   if (p.search(/[!@#\$%\^&\*_]/) < 0) {
        errors.push("Your password must contain at least special char from -[ ! @ # $ % ^ & * _ ]"); 
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        console.log(errors.join("\n"));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the length seperately, you can do the following:

```
var regularExpression  = /^[a-zA-Z]$/;

if (regularExpression.test(newPassword)) {
    alert("password should contain atleast one number and one special character");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you remake account password make sure it's 8-20 characters include numbers and special characters like `##\/*` - then verify new password and re enter exact same and should solve the issues with the password verification

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please provide a code sample for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

my validation shema - uppercase, lowercase, number and special characters

```
new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9_])")
```

Answer (score 1):

Pattern & RE for passwords with upper case, and lower case alphabets, a number, and special characters.

> pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$"

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the above answers and tested them, but there are several special characters, thus the complete password validation with at least one `small letter`, `big letter`, `number` and at least 8 characters in total should be:

```
/^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~])[a-zA-Z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~*]{8,}$/
```

I have tested it in my application and it works. Here I'm attaching the sample:

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const [input, setInput] = useState('');
    const [result, setResult] = useState('');
    const [isValidPassword, setIsValidPassword] = useState(false);
    const onValueChanged = (val) => {
      setInput(val);
      
      setIsValidPassword(
      /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~])[a-zA-Z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~*]{8,}$/.test(
        val
      )
    );
      console.log(isValidPassword);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <input placeholder="Enter password" value={input} onChange={(e)=> onValueChanged(e.target.value)}/>
            
            {
            isValidPassword? <h2>It is indeed valid password</h2>: <h2>It is not valid password</h2>
            }
        </div>
    );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems no one answered this yet:

```js
[ -~]
```

(Note the beginning **space**)

It denotes ASCII printable characters [from \x20 to \x7E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters), which
can represents all possible input for a password, include numbers, letters and symbols, except those control characters.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/**
 * @param {string} value: passwordValue
 */
const checkPasswordValidity = (value) => {
  const isNonWhiteSpace = /^\S*$/;
  if (!isNonWhiteSpace.test(value)) {
    return "Password must not contain Whitespaces.";
  }

  const isContainsUppercase = /^(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/;
  if (!isContainsUppercase.test(value)) {
    return "Password must have at least one Uppercase Character.";
  }

  const isContainsLowercase = /^(?=.*[a-z]).*$/;
  if (!isContainsLowercase.test(value)) {
    return "Password must have at least one Lowercase Character.";
  }

  const isContainsNumber = /^(?=.*[0-9]).*$/;
  if (!isContainsNumber.test(value)) {
    return "Password must contain at least one Digit.";
  }

  const isContainsSymbol =
    /^(?=.*[~`!@#$%^&*()--+={}\[\]|\\:;"'<>,.?/_₹]).*$/;
  if (!isContainsSymbol.test(value)) {
    return "Password must contain at least one Special Symbol.";
  }

  const isValidLength = /^.{10,16}$/;
  if (!isValidLength.test(value)) {
    return "Password must be 10-16 Characters Long.";
  }

  return null;
}

//------------------
// Usage/Example:
let yourPassword = "yourPassword123";
const message = checkPasswordValidity(yourPassword);

if (!message) {
  console.log("Hurray! Your Password is Valid and Strong.");
} else {
  console.log(message);
}
```

Comment: Hello! It would be great if you could explain how this code answers the question. Currently, it is unclear what your solution does. - [from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/34850114)