# Form Password Validation without using regex

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a password validation without using regular expression so yeah only javascript no pattern or regex. The format must contain 1 uppercase letter,1 lowercase letter,1 number and 1 special character.So the format must be like this :

aaaa111 -> Invalid format

AaAa111 -> Invalid format

A@Ba213 -> Valid format

EDIT: im so sorry i dont know that regex include in javascript.. iam trying this validation but didnt work

```
    var hasBigLetter   = false;
    var hasSmallLetter = false;
    var hasNumber      = false;
    var hasSpecialCaseLetter      = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < pass.length; i++) {
      var charCode = pass.charCodeAt(i);
      if(charCode > 47 && charCode < 58)
        hasNumber = true;
      if(charCode > 64 && charCode < 91)
        hasBigLetter = true;
      if(charCode > 96 && charCode < 123)
        hasSmallLetter = true;
      if(charCode > 32 && charCode < 48)
        hasSpecialCaseLetter   = true;


    }
if(pass == hasBigLetter && hasSmallLetter && hasNumber && hasSpecialCaseLetter)
    {
        alert("incorrect password pattern");
    }
```

HTML:

```
    <label> 
        Password : 
            <div>
             <input type="password" placeholder="Input Password" id="pass" name="pass" >
            </div>
    </label>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" onClick="validate()"> 
    </form>
```

Comment: So... what did you try?

Comment: why aren't you using regex?

Comment: Do you know how to test if a letter is uppercase ? Yes ? So what's the problem ?

Comment: Wtf. Why not RegEx? It's part of JavaScript, it is JavaScript

Comment: Are you trying to be cool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you now accepted to use RegEx, I adapted the solution based on this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/16707675/4339170:

```js
function validate() {
  var p = document.getElementById('pass').value
  var errors = []

  //if (p.length < 8) {
  //  errors.push("Your password must be at least 8 characters")
  //}
  if (p.search(/[a-z]/) < 0) {
    errors.push("Your password must contain at least one lowercase letter.")
  }
  if (p.search(/[A-Z]/) < 0) {
    errors.push("Your password must contain at least one uppercase letter.")
  }
  if (p.search(/[0-9]/) < 0) {
    errors.push("Your password must contain at least one digit.")
  }
  if(p.search(/[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\.\,\;\:\-]/) < 0) {
    errors.push("Your password must contain at least one special character.")
  }
    
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML = errors.join("<br>")
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<label>
  Password :
  <div>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Input Password" id="pass" name="pass">
  </div>
</label>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" onClick="validate()">
<div id="errors"></div>
```

Comment: oh waow tyvm you are godsend